# Stacking custom Tailwind variants with responsive variants

Tags: tailwind-css

Github discussion also opened [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/4662).

[Demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/YBxIfSKKwr?file=config) of what I'm trying to accomplish.

How do you make any `custom variants` you create stack-able with the `responsive` variants?
I want my new variant to be able to be changed responsively, but the `sm/md/lg` don't seem to stack with any new variant that I create.

I know you can apply the responsive variants to any new `utilities` that you create with `addUtility`, but how do I make sure my custom variants can be changed responsively?

Answer (score 1):

With this line you removed every single variants (even responsive) except for `custom-checked`. So change

```
variants: { scale: ['custom-checked'] }
```

to

```
variants: { 
    extend: { 
      scale: ['custom-checked'] 
    },
 },
```

It should do the trick. Full config will be

```
module.exports = {

  variants: { 
    extend: { 
      scale: ['custom-checked'] 
    },
  },

  plugins: [
    plugin(({ addVariant, e }) => {

      addVariant('custom-checked', ({ modifySelectors, separator }) => {
        modifySelectors(({ className }) => {
          return `.${e(`custom-checked${separator}${className}`)}:checked`
        })
      })
      
    }),
  ],
}
```